# Pyplot historgram with more than 7 datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram, bar-chart

Pyplot lets you create stacked histograms of multiple datasets (like [this one](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/mpl_examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended_04.png)).

However, if I have more than 7 datasets in the histogram, it repeats the color.

[image]

Is there a way to differentiate beyond 7 different colors?

I tried using the optional hatch argument ([documented here](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Patch.set_hatch)), but it only takes one hatch style for all bars, not one hatch style for each bar.

```
# This applies one hatch-style to all bars
plt.hist(data, label=label, normed=True, stacked=True, hatch='/')

# This doesn't apply different hatch styles to different bars.
# It throws an error
plt.hist(data, label=label, normed=True, stacked=True, hatch=
         ['/', '\\', '|', '-', '+', 'x', 'o', 'O', '.', '*', 'oo', 'xx'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib uses a color cycle with predefined colors. You could modify this color cycle to your liking, but it is cleaner if you directly specify the colors in the call to `hist`. It is tedious to specify the colors manually, so you could use one of matplotlibs colormaps to generate them. In the example below, I also used a colormap from [colorbrewer](http://colorbrewer2.org/) as those are quite nice too.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import brewer2mpl

colors_brewer = brewer2mpl.get_map('Paired', 'Qualitative', 12).mpl_colors
colors_jet = plt.cm.jet(np.linspace(0,1,12))

# random data 
data = np.random.rand(100,12)

# plot it
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax[0].hist(data, bins=10, stacked=True, color=colors_brewer)
ax[1].hist(data, bins=10, stacked=True, color=colors_jet)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]